# Renaming a directory in Python

Tags: python, directory, rename

I'm trying to rename a directory in `Python`, such hat the directory will be renamed to its first 8 characters of its original name.

This is what I did:

```
import os

path = '/home/directories'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        new_name = directory[0:8]
        os.rename(directory, new_name)
```

I however get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "xyz.py", line 8, in <module>
    os.rename(directory, new_name) 
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify full path of directory

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\demo_test_eg'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
       new_name = directory[0:8]
       path1 = path + "\\"+ directory#Full path of directory
       new_path = path + "\\"+new_name#Full path of file whose name is changed
       os.rename(path1, new_path)
```

> Note :
>
> I have added "\\" for windows

Comment: using `os.path.join` is the preferred way

Comment: yes os.path.join can also be used