# Find the most recent folder from directory and rename it

Tags: python

I am trying to rename the most recent folder in a directory but getting the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Program Files\\Ampps\\www\\DAT_Simulation\\Practice' -> 'C:\\Program Files\\Ampps\\www\\DAT_Simulation\\Practice\\lolol'
```

My code is the following:

```
import os
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(d)]
a = sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=True)[:1]
current_name = ''.join(a)

path = r"C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\DAT_Simulation\Practice"
b = os.path.join(path, current_name)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in dirs:
        # Apply input argument here
       new_name = 'lolol'
       new_path = path + "\\"+new_name
       os.rename(path, new_path)
```

Got my help from the following links:
[Renaming a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467226/renaming-a-directory-in-python)
[How to get the newest directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983705/how-to-get-the-newest-directory-in-python)

**EDIT:** As stated in the comments the loop was not necessary. And I should't be using path at the end.

```
new_name = 'lolol'
new_path = path + "\\"+new_name
os.rename(b, new_path)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `path` to find `current_name`?

Comment: Sorry, i am new to python. Do you mind explaining a bit more your question?

Comment: If you don't need `path` to compute `current_name`, why do you need it to compute `b` which you never use?

Comment: My guess: you want to call `os.listdir` with `path`, instead of `"."`, then `os.rename(b, new_path)`. The loop at the end seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it